# Create table where table name is a variable

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am creating a progress tracker for a school.

The progress tracker stores scores for each student in various threads and criteria within the threads.

I am currently planning on using a table per class (of students) which stores their progress in each thread and then a table per thread which stores their progress in each criteria within that thread.

I have no way of knowing how many classes (tables) are going to be in the school so I need to find some way of allowing the Administrator accounts to create classes (tables) with a name specified by the Admin.

The easiest way I thought of doing this was with using variables as the table name upon creation but there could be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why are you creating tables per user?  Why not just have a master table and a column that delineates the user?  Creating tables based on user input seems like a bad idea.

Comment: But to answer your question, you'd just build the appropriate SQL statement with a placeholder for the table name and insert the table name (e.g. using `string.Format`) - you cannot use parameters for table names.

Comment: @DStanley

Heya, thanks for your reply. The program is a progress tracker for a school and I'm storing the student progress in tables. one class is one table and the user needs to be able to create classes

Could you provide an example of how to create a table using the method described? I am not very skilled in c# and not sure how that would work.

Thanks :)

Comment: When you say 1 class is 1 table, do you mean c# class or an actual class e.g. English or Maths?

Comment: Don't do that - create a table called "Classes" and a foreign key from the progress table to the class table.  Unless you have a very good reason to create multiple identical tables, then it is a bad design.

Comment: @DStanley Updated the question

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "threads" but I still don't see a compelling need to have a separate table per class.  You are fragmenting your data unnecessarily.  Then adding a "class" is as simple as inserting a row into the "Classes" table.  Plus, all queries to _get_ the data will have to specify the table name dynamically, so your are going to have to use dynamic SQL everywhere.

Comment: Updated my answer to give an example of how I would attempt to structure the database based on your criteria.

Answer (score 4):

You CAN do something like that, but as D Stanley highlighted you can't use parameters for table names. As such you wouldn't be able to parameterise the user's input if that's to be used as the table name and therefore it makes it a very bad idea. This would immediately open you up to SQL injection, which is never a good plan.

Even with tight sanitization of the user's input there are too many variables to consider, which no doubt require far more work than desired and could still fall prone to attacks as sql evolves.

I would suggest rewording your question to perhaps giving a general idea of what your app is trying to achieve to see if there's another way forwards without creating a table per user.

***UPDATE***

Based on your rewording of your question it sounds like you need to think about your desired database structure. I'd be tempted to have the following tables:

- Students, with 1 entry per student, primary key of StudentId
- Classes - with 1 entry per class, primary key of ClassId
- Criteria - 1 entry per type of class criteria, primary key of CriteriaId
- Progress - potentially multiple entries per student referencing the StudentId, ClassId, CriteriaId and the Score (perhaps ClassScore and CriteriaScore).

You could then have queries to the Progress table that pulled out a student's progress based on just their Id, or their Id and ClassId, or further still their Id, ClassId and CriteriaId etc.

In terms of allowing Admins to create their own you'd simply create queries that allow Admins to insert student records into the Student table, classes into the Class table and criteria into the Criteria table. On creating a Student record you'd also presumably capture their classes and criteria at the same time, which would insert their record into the Progress table (initially 0 for progress so far). You'd presumably also want an update statement to allow admins to update the Progress table for any given student.

Anyway, hopefully this is enough of a pointer to enable you to not have to create a table per student or per class etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstable you must create the database and the Table (or you can create it later using C#). You must connect C# with SQL using the resources files, which is something like this example

```
Provider=XXXXXX.DataSource.1 ; Data Source=XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.CXXX;
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXX;pASSWORD=XXXXXX;
Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Force Translate=0;
Catalog Library List=XXXXXX,XXXXX
```

Then you create a SQLConnection object, create the connection with this method

```
CreateConnection()
```

Select the one you put in your resx file (or Resources) with this method:

`NameOfObject.ConnectionString = ConnStr();

and use this method to Open it `NameOfObject.Open();`

Now you can insert, delete, execute queries with this structure, you finally must get in your code something like this:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"); //Here you can put the string that you'll use in your resx file
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); //Initialize the command object for executing instructions (queries)
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME_HERE VALUES (" + nameYouWillExtractFromTheUser + ")";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //We say that the command is a textType
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1; //Initiate the connection

sqlConnection1.Open(); //Opens the connection

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //Execute the connection
```